# Livewire set variable with method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to fill a public variable using a method.
I have a Table class. I want to add my columns in the page controllers.
I want to create a table like this:

```
$table = (new Table())->model(Page::class)->columns([
        (new TextColumn())->make('standardLanguage.title')
            ->label('Titel'),
        (new TextColumn())->make('created_at')
            ->label('Aangemaakt op')
    ]);
```

The problem I have is that he column variable is null at the render.
My Table class extends the livewire Component.
In the Table class I have a public array $columns.

```
    trait HasColumns
{
    public array $columns = [];

    protected function resolveColumns(): Enumerable
    {
        return collect($this->columns);
    }

}
```

In the table component I have a columns function:

```
 public function columns($columns){
        $this->columns = $columns;
        return $this;
    }
```

When I dd() before the return I see my columns.

In the render method I have this:

```
public function render(): View
    {
        return view($this->view, [
            'paginator' => $this->paginate(),
            'table' => [
                'columns' => $this->resolveColumns(),
            ],
            'perPageOptions' => $this->perPageOptions()
        ]);
    }
```

The resolveColumns() is null. If I `dd($this->columns)` before the return it returns null.

I also tried adding the mount method, but that did not work either.

```
public function mount($columns){
        $this->columns = $columns;
        return $this;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I set the column variable using a method?

Comment: Do you by chance have a codepen so we can have a full look at how the code is operating?

Comment: @Yinci no, I do not have a codepen. But what I was trying to do is apparently not possible with livewire. Sice it only persists public data.

Comment: Yeah, protected or private data does not persist, but there's workarounds if you don't want to have data shared to the frontend, such as calling a method on each render cycle.

Comment: @Yinci do you happen to have an example of this? Or is there some documentation somewhere?

Comment: Made one for you: https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/a451a9db-6332-4244-8e41-b7466ecaf75d